# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : 'Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist'

Tags: c#, mysql

My c# program give me this error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : 'Table 
'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist'
```

Then I came across this answer:
[Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967527/table-performance-schema-session-variables-doesnt-exist#33262719)

I don't know where to write this command, knowing that I use EasyPhp.

Is this the Windows command prompt?

Is it mysql shell?

Thank you in advance for helping me to see things more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you linked to (`mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force`) is run on the MySQL Server, either at a Windows Command Prompt (if a Windows server) or a bash (or similar Unix shell prompt) on Linux. You may need to get your server administrator to run it for you.

The `performance_schema.session_variables` table is only available in MySQL Server 5.7.6 and later. If you're running an earlier version (or a different DB server, such as MariaDB), this table may not exist, causing the error you're seeing.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, but do I have to add performance_schema.session_variables to the MySql folder?

Comment: @WitzigAdrien No; this schema is automatically generated by the MySQL Server.