# Unable to setup Ruby on Rails localhost on my system

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working on Ruby on Rails : I have set up my local, Localhost:3000 but its not working, on debugging it shows 'performance_schema.session_variable' not found .. Issue is, I have never set up any such table , don't have such schema or database as well. I have been using my local to develop & debug but never once used this table/schema. I only run cmd and redis. My sql workbench says can't connect to DB so i am totally stuck.. please help !

I have been using this since 2 years but never this issue came, now after i got a new system, this issue is coming. I only use CMD & Redis.. what to do? How to get this performance_schema.session_variable & session_storage ?? How to finally run my Ruby on Rails localhost?

Comment: see it that here helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967527/table-performance-schema-session-variables-doesnt-exist

Comment: That sounds like a botched MySQL install, so if you're sure there's no important data in there, scrub and reinstall it.